# HTTP response print as [object Object],[object Object] in angular

Tags: angular, http

This is my price.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PriceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProduct(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products');
  }
}
```

This is price-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { PriceService } from './price.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-price-list',
  templateUrl: './price-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./price-list.component.css']
})
export class PriceListComponent implements OnInit {
  disableSelect = new FormControl(false);
  selectedValue :any
  sessions: any=[]
  constructor(private priceService: PriceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.priceService.getProduct().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.sessions = Object.values(data);

   });
  }
}
```

I try to print response within my price-list.component.html as below

> {{sessions}}

But it print below out put

> [object Object],[object Object]

This is my postman output

> [
> {
> "id": 8,
> "name": "Penguin-ears",
> "cartonPrice": 175,
> "unitPrice": 9.0,
> "unitForCarton": 20
> },
> {
> "id": 9,
> "name": "Penguin-earsghhc",
> "cartonPrice": 175,
> "unitPrice": 9.0,
> "unitForCarton": 20
> }
> ]

How can I print actual data

Comment: Use {{sessions | json}}

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the object directly into the HTML. if you want to see it as text, you should do as follow:

```
{{ JSON.stringify(sessions) }}
```

Comment: I want to print it as array

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you would want to display it as a html ul element. Then you could proceed as follows:

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let sessionItem of sessions">
    <li *ngFor="let keyVal of sessionItem | keyvalue"> {{ keyVal.key }}: {{ keyVal.value }}</li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```